# PayPal Express Checkout Capture Funds

Tags: php, paypal

I have written and successfully processed paypal functions on my clients site.  They just want to be able to finalize the bill after they have shipped the product as the cost is very hard to calculate as products vary in size, quantity, ect. I currently have it set up so that they authorize a payment after using express checkout API as I have set `$paymentType = "Authorization";` in stead of `sale` as the `paymentType`. All orders are tracked and logged in the database of the clients site they get a list of what the customer ordered, shipping info, ect on the admin side of the site. Only problem is once they have completed the order they mark it done on their site they must log into paypal and finalize the order by `capturing the funds`. How would I go about to capture funds using the classic API? I have found how to do it using the `rest api`, but I'm not going to rewrite my site to do it.

From the research I have done I have found that you can do it as I stated with the `rest api` and `nvp or merchant api`, but I'm using Express Checkout in PHP. I haven't been able to find how to use PHP and capture the funds.

My current code set up looks like this

```
//Orders are listed out using an array of mysql databases
......
**Where I need assistance**
//Capture funds from Paypal here 
//return status of successful via self posting form
....
//And then I have
//a get function that marks the order as completed in the database
```

To summarize my question is how would(if possible) using the classic api and express checkout capture funds from paypal? As you can see I have given some thought to this I'm just stuck and can't figure it out.

Comment: Do you have specific questions? What have you tried?

Comment: I simply haven't been able to find how you would do it with out rewriting my entire site as it seems to be all done with rest api, but nowhere does it explain how to do it with the classic api and php.

Comment: Why not use the REST API?

Comment: The REST API and the EC API dont work together so well :).

Answer (score 1):

The [DoCapture](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoCapture_API_Operation_NVP/) API is what you're looking for.  You'll pass in the transaction ID you got back from the Express Checkout Authorization along with the amount you're capturing.